# CMD unwanted line spacing

Tags: batch-file, cmd, line

I im writing a small program. When I wanted to do more user friendly interface I ended up with 
unwanted line spacing. How can I get rid of that?

This is a picture of this unwanted line spacings.

[image: capture]
<sub>(source: [shrani.si](http://shrani.si/f/2B/NA/1z2UfrDu/capture.png))</sub>

This is my code:

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=42z68tXk

```
@echo off
echo    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo                           WHAT DO YOU WANT TO DO
echo    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo    #                                                                        #
echo    #  1 - Random stuff                                                      #
echo    #                                                                        #
echo    #  2 - ghkfhhglk                                                         #    
echo    #                                                                        #
echo    #  3 - jgfjhdchgggggggggggh                                              #          
echo    #                                                                        #
echo    #  4 - hggggggggggggggggggggggdd                                         #         
echo    #                                                                        #
echo    #  5 - gdhhfgdfdfsdfg                                                    #              
echo    #                                                                        #
echo    #  6 - Bfgsgfsfgsfgsg                                                    #     
echo    #                                                                        #
echo    #  7 - hdfhsgsfgsgfsgsfgsfg                                              #          
echo    #                                                                        #
echo    #  8 - ssfgfsgfsgfsfgs                                                   #        
echo    #                                                                        #              
echo    #  9 - shfjhfjfghjkhjjjjjjjjj                                            #      
echo    #                                                                        #       
echo    #                                                                        #
echo    #  00 - fgsgfsfgsgsgf                                                    #          
echo    #  X - sgfsgfsgfsgfsfgs                                                  # 
echo    #                                                                        # 
echo    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
pause >nul
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for better control of unwanted trailing spaces/tabs just write it in brackets:

```
@echo off
(echo    --------------------------------------------------------------------------)
(echo                           WHAT DO YOU WANT TO DO)
(echo    --------------------------------------------------------------------------)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your batch file has a lot of invisible spaces after last meaningful character in some lines. Simply clean them up, and your problem will go away.

Some editors have ability to show invisible spaces or tabs, use it!

Answer (score 0):

This is due to spaces.
Try this code. Hope u can visualize the length of the scroll bar in both the code sections.

```
@echo off
echo    #                                                                        #
echo    #  1 - Random stuff                                                      #
echo    #                                                                        #
echo    #  2 - ghkfhhglk                                                         #
echo    #                                                                        #
echo    #  3 - jgfjhdchgggggggggggh                                              #
echo    #                                                                        #
echo    #  4 - hggggggggggggggggggggggdd                                         #
echo    #                                                                        #
echo    #  5 - gdhhfgdfdfsdfg                                                    #
echo    #                                                                        #
echo    #  6 - Bfgsgfsfgsfgsg                                                    #
echo    #                                                                        #
echo    #  7 - hdfhsgsfgsgfsgsfgsfg                                              #
echo    #                                                                        #
echo    #  8 - ssfgfsgfsgfsfgs                                                   #
echo    #                                                                        #
echo    #  9 - shfjhfjfghjkhjjjjjjjjj                                            #
echo    #                                                                        #
echo    #                                                                        #
echo    #  00 - fgsgfsfgsgsgf                                                    #
echo    #  X - sgfsgfsgfsgfsfgs                                                  #
echo    #                                                                        #
pause >nul
```